# Implementing classes that define three shapes in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, tostring

I think I've implemented everything asked within these set of instructions:

Design and implement a set of three classes that define shapes: RoundShape, Sphere, Cone. For each class, store fundamental data about its size and provide methods to access and modify this data. In addition, provide appropriate methods to compute the area, and volume, for Sphere and Cone. In your design, consider how shapes are related and thus where inheritance can be implemented. Don't create duplicate instance variables. Create a main method which instantiates 2 Sphere objects (any parameters), 2 Cone objects (any parameters), display them with ToString(), change one parameter (your choice) in each, and display them again.

Here is my code:

```
class RoundShape{
    double shape = 9;
    double radius = 4;
    int cone1 = 3;
    int sphere1;

    public String toString(){
        return  " the man" + cone1 + "this also" + sphere1;
    }

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
// class Sphere that extends RoundShape
//--------------------------------------------------------------
class Sphere extends RoundShape{
    double getArea(){
        double area = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return area;
    } // end of getArea

    double getVolume(){
        double volume = (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        return volume;  
    } // end of getVolume
} // end of the class Sphere

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// class Cone that extends RoundShape
//---------------------------------------------------------------
class Cone extends RoundShape{
    double height = 8;
    double getArea(){
        double area = Math.PI * radius * (radius + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(radius, 2)));
        return area;
    } // end of getArea for Cone

    double getVolume(){
        double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * (height/3);
        return volume;
    } // end of getVolume for Cone
} // end of the class Cone



public class Murray_A03A4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere();
            sphere1.getArea();
            sphere1.getVolume();
        System.out.println(sphere1);

        Cone cone1 = new Cone();
            cone1.getArea();
            cone1.getVolume();
        System.out.println(cone1);

    } // End of class header

} // End of method header
```

My main question is, how do I refer back to the toString method from content thats in the main method? Additionally, is the toString found within the correct class or should I place it in a new class or should I create a toString for every class?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement `toString()` methods in both `Sphere` & `Cone`. In those `toString` methods, put details specific to those classes and for the fields of the superclass invoke `super.toString()`

For Cone, it would be like :

```
public String toString() {
     return height + super.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `super`  allows you to access parent class and interfaces.
Also, feel free to use *casting*:

```
var self = (BaseOfBase)super;
self.VirtualMethod();
```

Turned up a lil bit with csharps' `base` which is completely same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is but what I think you're trying to ask for is: "How to call the `toString` method on `Sphere` objects and `Cone` objects when in the `main` method they are simply `RoundObject`?"

You should Override the toString method in every class, and it should return the information relevant to that class. So the `RoundObject` does not need return the volume, just the radius (maybe something like `return "RoundShape with radius " + radius;`). Then you would do the same for sphere and cone, but it would also include the shapes volume.

Then in `main`, you can simply call the `toString` method on the `RoundObjects`. Because the `toString` method is an instance method (doesn't have the static keyword in its title) it is [dynamically bound](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html). Meaning, the method from the actual underlying object will be used.

I see that you are trying to pull sphere/cone fields (sphere1, cone1) into `RoundObject` but this is not required. (it's actually better for a parent to not know anything about child classes)

for more information, look up [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt_XFk6PR_M).